# Indexing JSONB keys/values which are in different unique keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, jsonb, jsonpath

in postgres, I have a below `jsonb` column which has around 5k keys along with values.

I want to filter these keys along with their values  where priority/ age is greater than some specific value and also want to order them by the same.

```
{
  "100": {
    "name": "test",
    "priority": 5,
    "age": 10
  },
  "101": {
    "name": "test2",
    "priority": 10,
    "age": 20
  },
  "102": {
    "name": "test3",
    "priority": 15,
    "age": 25
  }                     
}
```

I am querying this  using jsonb_path_query as below.

`jsonb_path_query(match_data_3.json, '$.keyvalue() ? (@.value.priority >1)'`

As these queries as taking more time, I want to add index for age / priority to make the filtering fast.

is it possible to achieve this ? if yes, how can I ? any help is much appreciated.

Most of the questions answered here have the indexes based on specific keys. like `data->> 'priority'`. But my root keys are different. couldn't find a suitable answer for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonb_path_query()` won't use an index, but you can add a WHERE condition using the `@?` operator to filter out rows that match your JSON path condition:

```
select x.*
from the_table
  cross join jsonb_path_query(the_column, '$.** ? (@.priority > 1 && @.age > 10)') as x
where the_column @? '$.** ? (@.priority > 1 && @.age > 10)'
```

A GIN index on `the_column` can potentially be used by the `@?` operator. You will need to test if that really improves the query speed.

---

The best solution however, would be to use a properly normalized data model which can be indexed and queried efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want to use the index, how can I achieve this in jsonb?

Comment: I tried adding the GIN index on the column, didn't see any improvement in the query time.